# Redirect to a link by clicking on a row which contains it

Tags: jquery, html-table, click

I have a table

```
<tr>
  <td>xxx</td>
  <td>yyy</td>
  <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('smth','')">Select</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
...similar here
</tr>
```

My goal is to redirect to the select page link by clicking on the row. I was trying to implement such  construction

```
$("table tr").click(function() {
  $(this).find("a").click();
});
```

and also a few tricks with `window.location` but it didn't help.

**UPDATED:**
I'm getting errors like 
[image]

Comment: What you have should work. Do you get any console errors?

Comment: Yes, I get errors. I updated my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("table tr").click(function() {
  eval($(this).find("a").attr("href"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this, rather than emulating click

```
$("table tr").click(function() {
 window.location.href= $(this).find("a").attr("href");
});
```